# C errors using Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

Me and my friend are working on a project that works like duck duck goose, and we are have problems using the linked list we are required to use. From a couple of test inputs, from what I could tell, there seems to be a problem when we insert the names (strings), its not saving properly to the LL, and because of that when we try to print it crashes. You can access the Project information here: http://tinyurl.com/DuckDuckBoot.

The sample input and output are as follows:

```
**Input**
2
3
Bob
Cody
John
2 2
8
Carol
Casey
Nick
Kirsten
Ben
Bo
Billy
Heather
3 4
**Output:**
Game 1:
Cody

Game 2:
Billy
Bo
Carol
Kirsten
Nick
```

And here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    char PlayerNames;
    struct Node *next;
}

Players;

void insert(Players *ptr, char PlayerNames);
void delete(Players *ptr, char PlayerNames);
void print(Players *Start, Players *ptr);

void main()
{
    int NumberOfGames, NumberOfDucks, Rounds, NumberOfPeople, i, j, k, m;
    char Names, data;
    Players *Start, *temp;
    Start = (Players *)malloc(sizeof(Players));
    temp = Start;
    temp -> next = Start;

    scanf("%d", &NumberOfGames);

    for (i = 0;i < NumberOfGames;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &NumberOfPeople);

        for (j = 0;j < 3;j++)
        {
            scanf("%s", &Names);
            insert(Start, Names);
        }

        scanf("%d %d", &Rounds, &NumberOfDucks);

        for (k = 0;k < Rounds;k++)
        {
            for (m = 0;m < NumberOfDucks;m++)
                Start -> next;

            delete(Start, data);
        }
    }

    printf("Game %i:\n", i);
    print(Start, Start -> next);
    printf("\n");
}

void insert(Players *ptr, char PlayerNames)
{
    Players *Start = ptr;

    while (ptr -> next != Start)
    {
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }

    ptr -> next = (Players *)malloc(sizeof(Players));
    ptr = ptr -> next;
    ptr -> PlayerNames = PlayerNames;
    ptr -> next = Start;
    printf("inserting\n");
    return ;
}

void delete(Players *ptr, char PlayerNames)
{
    printf("deleting\n");
    Players *Start = ptr;

    while (ptr -> next != Start && (ptr -> next) -> PlayerNames != PlayerNames)
    {
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }

    Players *temp;
    temp = ptr -> next;
    ptr -> next = temp -> next;
    free(temp);
    return ;
}

void print(Players *Start, Players *ptr)
{
    printf("printing\n");

    if (ptr == Start)
        return;

    printf("%s", ptr -> PlayerNames);
    print(Start, ptr -> next);
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Format better your question, **compile with all warnings and debugging info** (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g`) and **learn to use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: And what's the question again?

Comment: Your problem begins way before you even approach a linked list. You don't know what's a string in C. Hint: `char` is not a string, it's a single character. Read an introductory text on C. K&R is good.